# Too many models in BayesFactor

Tags: r, bayesian

Using the BayesFactor package in R I get an error message according to which the number of models exceeded the default max.
According to the package's documentation "An option is included to prevent testing too many models:
options('BFMaxModels'), which defaults to 50,000, is the maximum number of models that will be analyzed at once. This can be increased by increased using options."

I do not know how to do this. How can I use options to increase the max?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried setting the option? E.g., `option(BFMaxModels=100000)`